# Animated image view, gets previous layout after another image animated

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I have an image view and show active screen with dot icon. When user scroll collectionview to change page, image view's x position setting center of selected page, and I have a searchbar on top of screen when press search button it show searchbar with animate but dot image getting back to first layout with animate

Here is my dot image view animation:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == collectionview  {
            let x = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
            if x >= 0.0 && x < 0.5 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectedDot.center.x = self.tabMainButton.center.x
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } else if x == 0.5 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectedDot.center.x = self.tabFavoriteButton.center.x
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } else if x > 0.5 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectedDot.center.x = self.tabFavoriteButton.center.x
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is function for search bar animation:

```
@IBAction func searchButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSearchActive {
            searchBar.endEditing(true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.searchHeight.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.searchHeight.constant = 56
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        self.collectionview.reloadData()
        isSearchActive = !isSearchActive
    }
```

Here are images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XoPE.png

Comment: So, what you want to achieve? An animation the will move the dot from one tab to another as user scrolls the content in middle of the screen.

Comment: when in the second screen dot image comes to  under second tabbar button but when user click the searchbar button and searchbar appears dot image suddenly goes first one under while user still in second screen  (second cell in collectionview)

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper is there any suggestion ?